# RemoveEventListener does not work on named function

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I am twisting my mind and fingers finding why `removeEventListener`won't work. It should be a one time event, so I included the `removeEventListener` in the callback function, but the event fires every time.

```
var group = ...//some div's ID
var img_button = document.createElement("SPAN");
    img_button.setAttribute("id","imgbutton_"+group);
if (figures.addEventListener){
    figures.addEventListener(
    'click', function(e){if (!e) e = window.event;e.stopPropagation();}, false);
    img_button.addEventListener(
    'mouseover', loadImg(group), false);
    }else{...};
```

And the callback `loadImg`:

```
function loadImg(nodeId){//loading images when needed
    return function(e){
        if (!e) e = window.event;
[...]
    //remove eventlistener when executed once
        var sp = (e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement);
        
        if (sp.removeEventListener){
            sp.removeEventListener(
            'mouseover', loadImg);
        } else {...};
};
```

The anonymous function can stay but the `loadImg` I only need once. What did I forget?

Comment: `loadImg` is not the name of the listener function. You've attached a function which is returned from `loadImg()`, and that function doesn't have a name (you can add it though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadImg` is not the name of the listener function. You've attached an anonymous function which is returned from `loadImg()`.

To solve this problem, you can give a name to the actual event handler function:

```
return function handler (e){
            :
    this.removeEventListener('mouseover', handler, false);
            :
}
```

[A working demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgnjbv5g/).

`this` in event handler refers automatically to the element to which the event was attached.

Comment: Thanks, Teemu. I gave a name to the anonymous returned function and tada!!

Comment: @elchmaen You're wellcome. Not exactly related, but it looks like you're also supporting old IEs (with legacy event handling model). If you've used `attachEvent/detachEvent` (recommended), you don't have to check the existence of `event` object, it's passed automatically. Also, there are some [issues with named function expressions](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs) in older IEs. They will work, but are causing some side effects, just take care you'll give an unique name to your handler.